# Why am I getting a NPE on bodyValue when trying to mock a WebClient call?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, mockito, spring-webflux

I have the following code I am trying to test...

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create(request.getEndpointUrl());
Mono<MessageResponseItem[]> response = client.post()
                                             .uri("...")
                                             .bodyValue(request) // NPE happens here
                                             .retrieve()
                                             .bodyToMono(MessageResponseItem[].class);
```

I try to make a unit test like this...

```
@PrepareForTest(WebClient.class)
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class MyServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private WebClient webClientMock;
    @Mock
    private WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec requestHeadersMock;
    @Mock
    private WebClient.RequestHeadersUriSpec requestHeadersUriMock;
    @Mock
    private WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec requestBodyUriMock;
    @Mock
    private WebClient.ResponseSpec responseMock;

    private MyService service = new MyService();

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(WebClient.class);
        BDDMockito.given(WebClient.create(any())).willReturn(webClientMock);
    }
    @Test
    public void HappyPath(){
        MessageResponseItem item = new MessageResponseItem();
        item.setRecipientId("id");
        item.setResponseText("response");
        MessageResponseItem[] items = {item};
        MyRequest request = new MyRequest();
        request.setSomething("something");
        ....
        when(webClientMock.post()).thenReturn(requestBodyUriMock);
        when(requestHeadersUriMock.uri("...")).thenReturn(requestHeadersMock);
        when(requestBodyUriMock.bodyValue(any(MyRequest.class))).thenReturn(requestHeadersMock);
        when(requestHeadersMock.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseMock);
        when(responseMock.bodyToMono(MessageResponseItem[].class)).thenReturn(Mono.just(items));
        MessageResponseItem[] result = service.callSomething(request).block();
        assertThat(result.length).isEqualTo(1);
        assertThat(result[0].getResponseText()).isEqualTo("response");
    }
}
```

So why am I not getting past the bodyValue without an NPE? Am I messing up the mocking?

I tried changing to...

```
@Mock
private WebClient.RequestHeadersUriSpec requestHeadersUriMock;
@Mock
private WebClient.RequestBodySpec requestBodyMock;
...
when(webClientMock.post()).thenReturn(requestBodyUriMock);
when(requestBodyUriMock.uri("...")).thenReturn(requestBodyMock);
when(requestBodyUriMock.bodyValue(any(MyeRequest.class))).thenReturn(requestHeadersMock);
when(requestHeadersMock.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseMock);
when(responseMock.bodyToMono(MessageResponseItem[].class)).thenReturn(Mono.just(items));
```

Same issue

Comment: can you post the complete test class ?

Comment: @AbdelghaniRoussi is there a part you are interested in? The issue is clearly in the mock and I just don't want to clutter the question. But if you are just looking for the mock definitions I can add those

Comment: I say that also because the uri line executes in the debugger

Comment: why are you initializing the `MyService`, isn't it a spring bean that should be autowired ?

Comment: @AbdelghaniRoussi thank you for trying to help, added the whole test. Again it wouldn't be breaking inside the service if that wasn't getting setup right. I could use it with Autowired if I was using something like SpringBootTest but that is not what I am doing for specific reasons that seem unrelated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after a little pairing:

```java
when(webClientMock.post()).thenReturn(requestBodyUriMock);
when(requestBodyUriMock.uri(any(String.class))).thenReturn(requestBodyMock);
when(requestBodyMock.bodyValue(any())).thenReturn(requestHeadersMock);
when(requestHeadersMock.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseMock);
when(responseMock.bodyToMono(MessageResponseItem[].class)).thenReturn(Mono.just(items));
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223994/discussion-between-jgleason-and-rob-evans).